# Faster long term exposures

Tags: camera

I want to take repeated long term exposures with the Raspberry Pi. I understand that the maximum exposure time is around 6 seconds. However, taking a 6 second exposure with raspistill takes over 40 seconds. How can I speed this up?

Here is the command and the time it takes to run:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ time raspistill -w 960 -h 720 -ss 6000000 -o img.jpeg

real    0m43.365s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.020s
```

Comment: Could you post the code you're using to take the long exposures? I'm mostly interested in the `capture()` call and whether it's using the still or video port.

Comment: @DaveJones See above.

Comment: Sorry - completely assumed you were using picamera - you're using raspistill which means it's the still port you're using. Just a mo and I'll grab some info on this...

Comment: Found it - I'd recommend having a read of [picamera ticket #227](https://github.com/waveform80/picamera/issues/227) to see if that sheds any light on the issue. Basically the answer is to do with the mode switching on the still port, so a video port capture would speed stuff up but would cost you quality

Comment: But the video port doesn't support 6s exposures. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: It does - although I can't remember if `raspivid` includes the necessary `FPS_RANGE` code.

Comment: Just checked and it does include the FPS_RANGE code, so you should be able to do 6s exposures with raspivid too - just bear in mind that AGC and AWB take *ages* to adjust at framerates that slow

Comment: Thanks. I'm still a little bit confused, but I'll experiment with it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Dave Jones' hints, I was able to get something working with raspivid. In case anyone else is looking for a solution, I use:

```
raspivid -awb sun -ex night -pf high -ISO 800 -g 1 -qp 10 -ss 6000000 -t 1200000 -b 100000000 -o out.mp4
```

Which gives this result:

https://youtu.be/8M4zXV36X0c